# How should I run power to a powered bidet toilet seat?

Tags: toilet, installation

Does anyone have a good solution for running a power cord for the [Toto 2034#01](https://www.totousa.com/washlet-c100-elongated) bidet toilet seat? I don't have an electric outlet behind my toilet and don't really want to install one. I am planning on running an extension cord (white) from the toilet to the wall outlet near my vanity, and then using these sticky things I found online to keep the cord in place and kind of out of the way. Not sure if it'll look good, or if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: Asking about return policies is a question for the vendor or manufacturer. Asking about running power cords is on-topic here.Is the wall outlet near your vanity GFCI protected? That is required by current code but many older bathroom outlets are not. Given the serious nature of a malfunction, I highly recommend GFCI (an easy and inexpensive upgrade) if you don't already have it.

Comment: The question is far too broad without a clear description of your situation (or photos). Please revise to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to use extension cords as a substitute for the fixed wiring of a structure.   NEC 400.6 -> 400.10 in the new Code.

What you want is *surface conduit*, something like Legrand Wiremold, starting at an existing recep or switch, and running along the wall or baseboard to where you need the power.   There, you install a receptacle box compatible with that conduit system.

The receptacle or switch where you started the conduit, gets moved outward onto the starter box's surface.  From there, you run THHN individual wires (black white green), to the new receptacle.  It's a lot like building LEGO but with some hacksawing on the conduit segments.  If you don't want to do the arcy sparky stuff, you can install the physical conduit (that's most of the work) then call a pro to connect the wires.

Further, you'll really, really want this extension circuit to be GFCI-protected, and the best way to do that is tap an existing GFCI receptacle.

Comment: To be clear, this doesn't allow running a cord through such conduit, right? You might say more about how you'd connect to the existing box. In my experience that's not a simple thing.